# How can i group data by month in mysql?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I tried to generate reports by monthly.

But at this line:

```
Dim startDate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(datefrom)
```

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Code:

```
getyear = Format(Date.Now, "yyyy")
Dim rmonth As Integer = 0
Dim datefrom As String
Dim dateto As String
If cmb_rmonth.Text = "January" Then
    rmonth = 1
ElseIf cmb_rmonth.Text = "February" Then
    rmonth = 2
ElseIf cmb_rmonth.Text = "March" Then
    rmonth = 3
End If


datefrom = getyear & "-" & rmonth & "-1"
dateto = getyear & "-" & rmonth & "-31"

Dim startDate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(datefrom)
Dim endDate As DateTime = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)

Call connectDB()
Dim dataset2 As New DataSet
Dim dataadapter2 As New MySqlDataAdapter(" SELECT taxi_no as 'Taxi No.', item_name as 'Item', quantity as 'Quantity', amount as 'Amount' FROM spare_parts WHERE date >= @from AND date < @to", sqlcon)
dataadapter2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", startDate)
dataadapter2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", endDate)

dataadapter2.Fill(dataset2, "spare_parts")
dgv_inventory.DataSource = dataset2.Tables("spare_parts")
Call disconnectDB()
```

Comment: I'm guessing you need two digits for the day in dateFrom: .... rmonth & "-01"

Comment: I already tried it but still getting the same result.

Comment: So then what does the value of dateFrom look like?

Comment: the value dateFrom is like this: 2017- 1 - 1 , is the format wrong??

Comment: Yes, I think so. It's usually YYYY-MM-DD, i.e. two digits for both month and day.

Comment: Also, it looks as if you have spaces in there too, which is definitely wrong. :-)

Comment: I'm having a problem on how to change the format since i can't put a number 0 in here  rmonth = 1 like  rmonth = 01, is there another way in getting the value of month??

Comment: Why not make it a string, since you're turning it into a string anyway? `Dim rmonth as String` ..... `rmonth = "01"` etc.

Comment: How about you don't use a `String` at all.  If you want to create a `Date` from components then do just that: `Dim startDate = New Date(Date.Now.Year, rmonth, 1)`. If you want the end date to be the end of the same month then do this: `Dim endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)`.

Comment: i tried to change its datatype to string, but it doesn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though  Ray O'Donnell :)

Comment: Oh I see, let me try. Thanks for the suggestion  jmcilhinney.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i tried it but it doesn't show result. :( When i tried to show the value of `startDate` it did not get the value of month which is supposed to be 1 , since `"january" = 1` .. the value of `startDate` is 2017-0-01.

Comment: No, it isn't. I can't possibly be. That does not represent a valid date and a `DateTime` must, by definition, represent a valid date.  You need to debug your code.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney I was stupid to found out that i wrongly named the combobox it supposed to be `cmb_imonth.text` rather than `cmb_rmonth.Text`. you're suggestion already worked! Thank you so much. It was my mistake to wrongly named the combobox.